# Kendo Grid: Clear Column Widths

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a grid that's width is 100%.  The columns size equals out among all columns when the grid first loads.
The user can then re-size columns to fit their need.
Now I need a way to reset all the columns back to defaults without reloading the page.

I tried refreshing the grid but that didn't work after the grid has already been bound:
`.data().kendoGrid.refresh()`

Comment: Is that a typo? Didn't you mean `$(element).data('kendoGrid').refresh()`?

Comment: No, I believe both should work.

Comment: It seems the data is being refreshed but not the column widths.

Comment: have you tried redraw()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a little trick (this is not perfect and might fail depending on your custom grid formatting). The trick is setting the widths to the same amount (ex. 100px). Something like:

Grid definition:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    resizable : true,
    pageable  : true,
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Code for resizing:

```
$("col", grid.element).css("width", "100px");
```

In addition, you might be interested on doing:

```
$("table", grid.element).css("width", "100%");
```

This resizes the "table" columns to use all the original space otherwise (just doing the `col` resizing) you might end-up with equally spaced cols but not using all the original width of the table).

You can see how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/a9QSr/